# What does it mean to "reproduce Morgan's equivalents along with Boolean Algebra"?

Tags: boolean-algebra

This is my first time attemting anything like this (not posting on the forum, the subject itself) and would like some guidance. It's more of the **guidance** side. Can someone start me off in the right direction or give me sources? I've done research for a few hours now but can't find any sources that help with my specific topic (or so I think).

So far, here's an image of the page I'm doing for a lab assignment. I don't need help with the few questions at the bottom, I'm just trying to figure out how to "reproduce" equivalents, whatever that means. How do I fill in the small little BAY charts in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are **truth tables**. And unfortunately they're incomplete. A full truth table with n variables will have 2<sup>n</sup> rows. The columns on the left are the inputs, and the columns on the right are the outputs. The values of the outputs are determined by both the inputs and the boolean equation for the circuit.

For instance:

```
Y = AB

A B Y
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

becomes:

```
A B Y
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks helps a lot, thanks! I appreciate it, it's a new class so I have no idea what this meant and your answer is my source from now on.